# If $A,B$ are two digits and $2(AB)=BA+30$, what is the value of $A+B$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $AB, BA \in \mathbb N$ be two numbers with two digits ($A$ and $B$). If

$$2(AB)=BA+30$$
what is the value of $A+B$?

Comment: Is $AB \ne BA$ {}{}{}{}

Comment: Do i understand it correctly, here $\overline{AB}=10A+B$ is a decimal two digits number, where the digits $A,B$ do not vanish... ?! If yes, please try to build some more sentences that make the situation clear, and add some content, e.g. starting with this $10A+B$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$2(AB) = 2(10A+B)= 20A+2B$$
$$BA+30 = 10B+A+30$$

Thus we want to have $$20A+2B=10B+A+30$$

That is $$19A=8B+30$$

One solution is $A=2$ and $B=1$ so $A+B=3$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner  $A=2, B=1$ works.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner  $2(21)=12+30 $